# Activating a scene for a room or a zone using Philips Hue API V2

Tags: philips-hue

I've been through the documentation and the guides but I found no way to activate a scene in the v2API. The PUT command on a scene seems to change the scene, and group_lights has no command to recall scene.
Where am I missing it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the scene ID, then you can use:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://{bridgeIp}/clip/v2/resource/scene/{sceneId}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'hue-application-key: {appKey}' \
--data '{"recall":{"action": "active"}}'
```

See API reference here: https://developers.meethue.com/develop/hue-api-v2/api-reference/#resource_scene__id__put

And examples here: https://github.com/jaaufauvre/philips-hue-auto-config